# Word for number or word that reads the same when inverted or mirrored

Tags: single-word-requests, palindrome

The number I am thinking of is 80808. This is a palindrome. However, it is more than a palindrome, because it can be flipped or mirrored and will still read the same way.

Is there a word for this?

Comment: HUH, MA'AM? AVA: dob 18.8.81 lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a term for words written in such a form that they can be read from another viewpoint, direction or orientation. They are called **ambigrams**. See the relevant [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram).

Answer (score 1):

[***Strobogrammatic number***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobogrammatic_number):

> A **strobogrammatic number** is a number that, given a base and given
>   a set of glyphs, appears the same whether viewed normally or upside
>   down by rotation of 180 degrees. (Wikipedia)

Comment: Hi Rose, welcome to the site and thanks for your contribution! Please always give the name of your source, and link to it if it is online. This is especially important when you give a direct quote like this. I've edited your post to add this information and to format the quoted material as a "block quote." Note that this Wikipedia article has a warning at the top saying "This article needs additional citations for verification." If you can find another source that verifies this information, that would make this a better answer.

Comment: While your answer is a correct example, it does not include mirrorring, which is also one of the traits the question describes. Still an interesting word to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you may want is [dihedral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DihedralPrime.html). The only numbers that can appear in such a construction are 0, 1, 2, 5, and 8, and the property primarily applies to numbers displayed on a calculator or using LED's.

There are also dihedral letters, namely the capitals H, I, O, and X.

Comment: What about M, T, U, V, W and Y (depending on font of course)? ;)

Comment: @njr They're not same upside-down.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realise what he meant by "flipped". Although you could still have M and W ;)

Comment: @njr101: No you can't. "80808**M**", when mirrorred, would still turn into "80808**W**" which is not the same as you can see.

Comment: @Flater: But by that logic, then why are "2" and "5" in the list from the poster? They are not the same either?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term you are looking for is: `mirror-image ambigram`

More on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram)...

Comment: looking at the example of Wiki image on the site, this will only work mirrored, but not flipped.

Comment: Yes, but it would be very easy to construct an ambigram that is both a mirror-image ambigram (either horizontally or vertically) and a rotational ambigram.

Comment: Yes, and what is the name for that ?