# Terminology for words that are the same backwards and forwards, upside-down or right way up

Tags: terminology, palindrome

I'm thinking of getting a SONOS sound system and have realised that it's an example of a special class of word.  It's a palindrome, it's a rotational ambigram and it is also a word that is the same upside down.

Any palindrome that uses, exclusively, H I N O S X Z (also some versions of lower case f and l) will share this characteristic .

Is there a special name for this ?

Comment: it's only the same upside-down if rotated, rather than reflected.

Comment: Thanks @PhilMJones. I've corrected my question. An additional term may be needed !

Comment: possible duplicate: [Word for number or word that reads the same when inverted or mirrored](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64552/word-for-number-or-word-that-reads-the-same-when-inverted-or-mirrored)

Comment: Not answered there clearly.  Would it be a dihedral or a tetradic ambigram !?

Comment: It was answered quite clearly in the linked question. It is a rotational ambigram. Your question was is there a special name and the answer is that it is a rotational ambigram. If you want something more descriptive you'll need to append some extra words on there to modify it to fit your needs. Language, yo.

Comment: Thanks @DaveMagner - the Wiki link is very good.  There's no doubt that SONOS is a rotational ambigram.  It is, however, a very special kind because the letters stay the same when they are inverted - in most (all ?) of the examples in the link the ambigram is achieved by pairs of letters (Ps and Ds, Bs and Qs, Ws and Ms etc).  Probably I should get out more, but it does seem to me that the SONOS case is a distinct sub-group of rotational ambigram (and not described  in the link) - dihedral or some adjective underlining the fact that the letters are constant in both versions.

Comment: That just means that it's _both_ a rotational ambigram and a palindrome. It's not clear that we need a special word for this combination.

Comment: I don't think so @Barmar.  Not all rotational ambigrams say the same thing with the same letters both ways.

Comment: @Dan I never said they do. `SONOS` is both a rotational ambigram and also a palindrome.

Comment: Maybe that's what we need a special word for - a rotational ambigram that is also a palindrome ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps "palindromic rotational ambigram"? I just stuck "palindromic" on the front of "rotational ambigram".

I don't think there's a term with fewer than three words to describe what you want.

(I'm not sure the distinction from "rotational ambigram" is necessary, as most rotational ambigrams seem to be palindromic--I'm guessing designing those is just easier--but it's your language. More concise is okay, and more words are okay.)

Comment: People clever with fonts seem to be able to make all kinds of rotational ambigrams that are not palindromic - see, for example, the illustrations on the right column, for *ambigram* and *chumps* - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram.  But you are probably right that I should be happy with palindromic rotational ambigrams !

Comment: (looking through old posts I see this should have had my tick - sorry for the delay!)